# WordPress dropdown menus overlapping - hovering one opens another

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

So I'm creating a theme for WP, and the menu is acting up. I suppose the dropdowns somehow overlap in the back, sometimes when I hover over one item, its submenu opens, but as I move the curses towards its submenu, the submenu of the item next to it opens instead.

Example:

[image: WordPress Overlapping Dropdown Menus]

Any ideas?

### EDIT:

I noticed that when I hover over a top-level menu item for more than 2 seconds and then move the curser towards the submenu, the glitch doesn't happen.

What I found after doing a lot of digging is that once I hover over a top-level menu item, there is a class being added to it by my theme (Divi), and when I move the curser to another, the class is removed, but with a certain delay, so when I hover over a new top-level menu item, the previously hovered one still has the class appended to it for about 1 second.

I found the following code in the theme's files and I assume it is to blame, however I tried changing the 200 to 0 and the delay is still taking place (I'm tracking the classes being added and removed as I hover using DevTools on Chrome):

```
window.et_pb_toggle_nav_menu = function($element, state, delay) {
    if ( 'open' === state ) {
        if ( ! $element.closest( 'li.mega-menu' ).length || $element.hasClass( 'mega-menu' ) ) {
            $element.addClass( 'et-show-dropdown' );
            $element.removeClass( 'et-hover' ).addClass( 'et-hover' );
        }
    } else {
        var closeDelay = typeof delay !== 'undefined' ? delay : 200;
        $element.removeClass( 'et-show-dropdown' );
        $element.removeClass( 'et-touch-hover' );

        setTimeout( function() {
            if ( ! $element.hasClass( 'et-show-dropdown' ) ) {
                $element.removeClass( 'et-hover' );
            }
        }, closeDelay );
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried playing with the `z-index` on hover?  Something like:

```
.item {
    z-index: 0;
    &:hover {
        z-index: 1;
    }
}
```

I'm guessing right now without the code to use as a reference.